# Using Hex colors with inline Styles with React from a graphQL query

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, inline

I am trying to replicate the pinned repos on a github profile, to display my own within my website.

I have a working query, and a working component. However the color outputted via the query is a hex colour.

```
return (
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-3 sm:grid-cols-2 mb-8">
            {data.github.user.pinnedItems.edges.map(({node}) => (
                <div className="flex flex-col justify-around border rounded-md">
                    <div className="p-4">
                        <div className="flex items-center mb-4">
                            <span className="h-3 w-3 mr-2"><GoRepo/></span>
                            <h2 className="font-semibold text-sm m-0">
                                <a href={node.url} className="">{node.name}</a>
                            </h2>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <p className="text-xs font-sans">{node.description}</p>
                        </div>

                        <div className="flex items-center mt-4">                                               
                            <span className="bg-yellow-600 rounded-full h-3 w-3"></span>
                            <span className="text-xs ml-2 font-sans text-gray-600">{node.primaryLanguage.name}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
```

The hex color is generated via `{node.primaryLanguage.color}` how can i use that hex color inline on the following?

`<span className="bg-yellow-600 rounded-full h-3 w-3"></span>` As I am currently just using `bg-yellow-600` before I can figure it out.

I have tried the following:

```
const bgColor = {
        backgroundColor: "{node.primaryLanguage.color}"
    }

    return (...

           <span style={bgColor} className="rounded-full h-3 w-3"></span>
```

I was hoping to use the string as once it's run in map, it will fill the hex code but nothing.

---

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby'
import { GoRepo } from "react-icons/go";

const PinnedRepos = () => {
    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query{
        github {
          user(login: "mrpbennett") {
            pinnedItems(first: 6, types: REPOSITORY) {
                edges {
                node {
                    ... on GitHub_Repository {
                    name
                    description
                    url
                    primaryLanguage {
                        name
                        color
                    }
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            }
        }
      }
    `)

    {data.github.user.pinnedItems.edges.map(({node}) => {

        const bgColor = {
            backgroundColor: node.primaryLanguage.color
        }

        return (
            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 sm:grid-cols-2">
                    <div className="flex flex-col justify-around border rounded-md">
                        <div className="p-4">
                            <div className="flex items-center mb-4">
                                <span className="h-3 w-3 mr-2"><GoRepo/></span>
                                <h2 className="font-semibold text-sm m-0">
                                    <a href={node.url} className="">{node.name}</a>
                                </h2>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <p className="text-xs font-sans">{node.description}</p>
                            </div>

                            <div className="flex items-center mt-4">                                               
                                <span stlye={bgColor} className="rounded-full h-3 w-3"></span>
                                <span className="text-xs ml-2 font-sans text-gray-600">{node.primaryLanguage.name}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        )
    })}
}

export default PinnedRepos
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget that what is wrapped between `{ }` in React is real JavaScript. What I mean is that your `.map()` is just a function, where you can add any additional logic.

You just have to transform the arrow function from shorthand return to function body:

```
return (
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-3 sm:grid-cols-2 mb-8">
          {data.github.user.pinnedItems.edges.map(({node}) => {
            const bgColor = {
              backgroundColor: node.primaryLanguage.color
            }

            return (
              <div className="flex flex-col justify-around border rounded-md">
                  <div className="p-4">
                      <div className="flex items-center mb-4">
                          <span className="h-3 w-3 mr-2"><GoRepo/></span>
                          <h2 className="font-semibold text-sm m-0">
                              <a href={node.url} className="">{node.name}</a>
                          </h2>
                      </div>

                      <div>
                          <p className="text-xs font-sans">{node.description}</p>
                      </div>

                      <div className="flex items-center mt-4">                                               
                          <span style={bgColor} className="rounded-full h-3 w-3"></span>
                          <span className="text-xs ml-2 font-sans text-gray-600">{node.primaryLanguage.name}</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          )})}
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for this now you have put it infront of my eyes, it makes sense now. I am still getting my head round React...now i have done what you said I am getting the `Error: PinnedRepos(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.`

Comment: My bad, I didn't copy your entire snippet, just the map part. I think your code is missing the `return ( <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-3 sm:grid-cols-2 mb-8">` part

Comment: hmmm still seem to be getting the same error, I have updated my question with my component. I am also getting this warning in the terminal ```/Users/paul/Developer/gatsby-me/src/components/github-pinned.js
  30:5  warning  Nested block is redundant  no-lone-blocks``` - line 30 is the following: `{data.github.user.pinnedItems.edges.map(({node}) => {...`

Comment: I've edited my code. It's your first snippet, with the `{ data.github(...) }` part updated.

Comment: Sir I tip my hat to you! This has taken me most of the afternoon. I see what you have done though. Thanks for the pointers and the help!